# Inserting multiple variables in sqlite - python

Tags: python, sqlite

What would be the best way to make a script takes a CSV (with n columns) and adds them into a sqlite db?

This is what I have till now -

```
def export_to_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_NAME)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    table_name = config.TABLE_NAME
    with open(config.IMPORT_FILENAME, 'rb') as csvfile:
        tablerows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = True # make this configurable
        for row in tablerows:
            if header:
                header = False
            else:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO <tablename> VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", tuple(row)) 
                # I want the number of columns to be same as teh number of columns in CSV.              
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from people")
    print str(cur.fetchone()[0]) + " rows added!"
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to make the number of columns configurable (the caller is supposed to know, isn't he ?) then build your insert statement based on this info. If you don't know how to do so, read the FineManual's part on string formatting.